# Assigning values to two dimensional array from two one dimensional ones

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Most probably somebody else already asked this but I couldn't find it. The question is how can I assign values to a 2D array from two 1D arrays. For example:

```
import numpy as np
#a is the 2D array. b is the 1D array and should be assigned 
#to second coordinate. In this exaple the first coordinate is 1.
a=np.zeros((3,2))
b=np.asarray([1,2,3])
c=np.ones(3)
a=np.vstack((c,b)).T
```

output:

```
[[ 1.  1.]
 [ 1.  2.]
 [ 1.  3.]]
```

I know the way I am doing it so naive, but I am sure there should be a one line way of doing this.

P.S. In real case that I am dealing with, this is a subarray of an array, and therefore I cannot set the first coordinate from the beginning to one. The whole array's first coordinate are different, but after applying `np.where` they become constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about 2 lines?

```
>>> c = np.ones((3, 2))
>>> c[:, 1] = [1, 2, 3]
```

And the proof it works:

```
>>> c
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  3.]])
```

---

Or, perhaps you want `np.column_stack`:

```
>>> np.column_stack(([1.,1,1],[1,2,3]))
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.],
       [ 1.,  3.]])
```

Comment: Thanks. Vote up, but the point is my first array is fixed but not for all values. So in real scenario I am actually using `np.where` and therefore the first value is 1, otherwise all the coords of first vector are not `1`. Some are `0` as well. But thanks I will update it.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's absolutely no reason to create the original `zeros` array that you stick in `a`, never reference, and replace with a completely different array with the same name.

Second, if you want to create an array the same shape and dtype as `b` but with all ones, use `ones_like`.

So:

```
b = np.array([1,2,3])
c = np.ones_like(b)
d = np.vstack((c, b).T
```

You could of course expand `b` to a 3x1-array instead of a 3-array, in which case you can use `hstack` instead of needing to `vstack` then transpose… but I don't think that's any simpler:

```
b = np.array([1,2,3])
b = np.expand_dims(b, 1)
c = np.ones_like(b)
d = np.hstack((c, b))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on 1 line, use [fancy indexing](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-0dffc419afa7d77d51062d40d2d84143db8216c2):

```
>>> a[:,0],a[:,1]=[1,1,1],[1,2,3]
```